# JPanel doesn't response to KeyListener event

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, keylistener

I have a subclass of `JFrame` that uses a class extended from `JPanel`

```
public class HelloWorld extends JPanel implements KeyListener
```

I add an object of `HelloWorld` to the frame - `app.add(helloWorld);`. Now, when I press any keyboard key non of the `KeyListener` methods gets called and it seems that `helloWorld` doesn't have window focus. I have tried also to invoke `helloWorld.requestFocusInWindow();` but still doesn't respond.

How can I make it respond to key press?

Comment: Look into [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  May or may not solve the problem, but a generally better approach for Swing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you set that `KeyListener` for your `HelloWorld` panel would be that panel itself? Also you probably need to set that panel focusable. I tested it by this code and it seems to work as it should

```
class HelloWorld extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped: "+e);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed: "+e);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyReleased: "+e);
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200,200);

        HelloWorld helloWorld=new HelloWorld();

        helloWorld.addKeyListener(helloWorld);
        helloWorld.setFocusable(true);

        add(helloWorld);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: dont forget to `grabFocus()` if you have custom mouselisteners

Answer (score 12):

JPanel is not Focusable by default.  That is, it can not respond to focus related events, meaning that it can not respond to the keyevents.

I would suggest trying to setFocusable on the pane to true and trying again. Make sure you click the panel first to make sure it receives focus.

Understand though, you WILL get strange focus traversal issues, as the panel will now receive input focus as the user navigates through your forms, making it seem like the focus has been lost some where.

Also, `KeyListener`s tend to be unreliable in this kind of situation (due to the way that the focus manager works).

Answer (score 1):

simple you have to add

```
addKeylistener(new HelloWorld());
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in MyFrame method;

```
HelloWorld() helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
this.addKeyListener(helloWorld);
```