# Java Keyboard input not working using KeyBindings - selfmade rendering engine at fault?

Tags: java, keyboard, key-bindings, 2d-games

So I've been working on building my own 2D game ("StarGame") from scratch for nearly a year now.
At first, the graphics were nothing more than some AWT rectangles/polygons with different colors, but recently, I decided to make the move to proper graphics and a friend of mine was willing to create some retro-styled images for me.
So far, so good.

The thing is: since I switched to proper graphics, my game does not recognize keyboard input anymore.
I was using KeyListener for the input at that time and **when searching for a solution**, the only thing that I thought made sense was to *move from KeyListener to KeyBindings*.
So I did that, *at no avail*.

### My debugging has only gotten me as far as this:

Key input works in the main menu.
Key input works on the credits screen.
Key input does *not* work when anything is drawn onto the screen at the game screen.

### My game works as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.mainMenu();
}
```

The constructor for Game initializes lots of variables, the important part:

```
public Game() {
    // ...
    window = new JFrame("StarGame Beta "+version);
    menuPanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    mainMenu = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("gifs/mainMenuBG.gif"));
    credits = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("gifs/credits.gif"));

    window.addWindowListener(windowAdapter);
    window.setBounds(new Rectangle(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    menuPanel.setFocusable(true);  // NEW, didn't fix it!
    gamePanel.setFocusable(true);  // NEW, didn't fix it!

    setTheKeyBindings();

    setNewGameState(MAIN_MENU);

    gameRenderer = new GameRenderer(gamePanel);
}
```

setTheKeyBindings() does as its name suggests, an excerpt:

```
    InputMap menuInputMap = menuPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    menuInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "runGame");
    ActionMap menuActionMap = menuPanel.getActionMap();
    menuActionMap.put("runGame", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            runGame();
        }
    });
```

The method runGame() stops menu music playback and fires the startGame() method:

```
private void runGame()
    {
        menuOggClip.stop();
        System.out.println("Running game");

        startGame();
        stopGame();

        menuOggClip.loop();
        showMainMenu();
    }
```

startGame() adds the JPanel gamePanel to the JFrame window and adds the in-game items and music:

```
public void startGame()
{
    window.remove(menuPanel);
    if(gameRenderer == null) {
        gameRenderer = new GameRenderer(gamePanel);
    }
    window.add(gamePanel);
    // See showMainMenu() for explanation
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);

    gameRenderer.add(ship);
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        rocks[i] = new Rock();
        gameRenderer.add(rocks[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        aliens[i] = new Alien();
        gameRenderer.add(aliens[i]);
    }
    //gameRenderer.setFirstRun(false);

    shotSound = new ShotSound();
    shotSoundThread = new Thread(shotSound);

    bgMusic = new BackgroundMusic();
    bgMusicThread = new Thread(bgMusic);

    setNewGameState(INTRO);
    System.out.println("Game initialized!");

    gamePanel.requestFocus();

    game();
}
```

There is a gameState variable that keeps track of what "state" the game currently is in, e. g. MAIN_MENU or GAME_RUNNING. The main game logic is a while(true) loop with a switch that determines what to do based on the game state:

```
       case GAME_RUNNING:
            gamePanel.requestFocus(); // this is just a failsafe to make sure the game stays in focus

            gameRenderer.remove(laser);

            if (!didICrash(ship.getShipRect())) { // if the player didn't crash, move the rocks/asteroids a bit to the left -> it seems like the ship is moving right.
                for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
                    rocks[i].tick();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (aliens[i].tick()) { // if the alien got to the left of the screen and respawned, add it again
                        gameRenderer.add(aliens[i]);
                    }
                    if (!aliens[i].isVisible()) { // if the alien is invisible, remove it from drawing queue
                        gameRenderer.remove(aliens[i]);
                    }
                }
                addToDistance(1);
            } else {
                setNewGameState(CRASHED);
            }

            // Animation
            repaint();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleep = sleepMax - timeDiff;
            if (sleep < 0) {
                sleep = 0;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
            break;
```

Every time/frame, that loop calls the *repaint()* method which in turn calls the three methods *clearScreen()*, *draw()* and *drawToScreen()* in this class:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GameRenderer {

    public JPanel gamePanel;
    public List<IDrawObject> listDOs;

    private BufferedImage completeImage;
    private Graphics2D g;

    private boolean firstRun = true;


    public GameRenderer(JPanel gamePanel) {
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
        listDOs=new ArrayList<>();
        completeImage = new BufferedImage(Game.WIDTH,Game.HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = completeImage.createGraphics();
    }


    public void clearScreen() {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
    }


    public void draw() {
        for(int i = 0; i < listDOs.size(); i ++) {
            listDOs.get(i).draw(g);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Essential method, called last in repaint(): Draws the entire image to the screen.
     */
    public void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = gamePanel.getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(completeImage, 0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT, null);
    }


    public void add(IDrawObject ido) {
        listDOs.add(ido);
    }
    public void remove(IDrawObject ido) {
        listDOs.remove(ido);
    }
    public JPanel getGamePanel() {
        return gamePanel;
    }
    public void setFirstRun(boolean firstRun) {
        this.firstRun = firstRun;
    }
}
```

After some more debugging I found out that even without any of the three drawing methods being called in the loop, keyboard input doesn't work.

So here's the question:

### How do I make my keyboard input work again and why is it not working?

I would seriously appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pieces of code you show do not show any KeyBinding installed on you GamePanel, which I guess would be the only panel in the window when the game is running? Also, JPanel may not respond to a KeyListener (and possibly also KeyBinding) by default, because its not focusable (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487369). Try making your panels focusable with setFocusable(true), and make sure you add your KeyBinding at the topmost, related container.

Comment: @Durandal Thanks for your tips. I have added gamePanel.setFocusable(true) to the Game() constructor, but that didn't help. The keyboard still only works in the main menu.
What do you mean by installing the KeyBinding on the gamePanel and what is the topmost container? My JFrame (I called mine  window)?

Comment: I wish every new user could ask questions like this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using your panels, I'm missing the place where you actually *add* them to your window; and I'm not sure if you have one or multiple key bindings (one per panel?) - with "topmost" I mean adding the binding to the outermost enclosing container, this *could* be the window (or its ContentPane), depending on if you have a single binding you're using in all "states" or one per state. Could you please add your code where you actually add the panel(s) to the window?

Comment: @Durandal
I added the methods runGame() and startGame() for further clarification.
runGame() just pauses the menu music and calls startGame();   startGame() is the interesting one as it adds the JPanel gamePanel to the JFrame Window, please see my updated post above.  
I have multiple KeyBindings for the different keys like S, C, ESCAPE and UP/DOWN. I differenciate the bindings per state by adding them to the relevant JPanel; for example in the GAME_RUNNING state the menuPanel is removed from the JFrame window.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to apply KeyBindings in a simplified test harness. The general pattern, attaching the binding at the panel level and switching panels was the same as you demonstrate in your code. I encountered several cases where the binding would not work, all based on which factory method was used to create the *KeyStroke*.

What did surprisingly *not work* was `getKeyStroke("s")`, it had to be `getKeyStroke("S")`.

You might want to adapt the switchPanel() approach, it might be that at some point you have multiple panels attached to your window (which you probably would not see, since your actively rendering) with conflicting key bindings. By simply removing whatever is attached to the frame, it makes sure that there is always only the one active panel.

Other than that, from all your code, I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Testing Sample:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeyBindingTest {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Demo");

    static class DemoPanel extends JPanel {
        private String text;

        public DemoPanel(String text) {
            this.text = text;
            setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString(text, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    JPanel menuPanel = new DemoPanel("S to Start");
    JPanel gamePanel = new DemoPanel("S to Stop");

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                KeyBindingTest game = new KeyBindingTest();
                game.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        setup();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setup() {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.add(menuPanel);
        bind(menuPanel, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "start",
                new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPanel(window, gamePanel);
                System.out.println("Start!");
            }
        });
        bind(gamePanel, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "stop",
                new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switchPanel(window, menuPanel);
                System.out.println("Stop!");
            }
        });
    }

    private void switchPanel(JFrame window, JComponent panel) {
        window.getContentPane().removeAll();
        window.add(panel);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }

    private static void bind(JComponent component, KeyStroke key, String string, Action action) {
        component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(key, string);
        component.getActionMap().put(string, action);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have implemented the switchPanel() method and modified my code to work with that properly. However, that did not solve my problem.
I think it is worth noting that even my WindowAdapter that I use to call an exit() method when the user closes the window stops working when the game starts and everything works again when the user returns to the main menu (which I had to simulate using code obviously).