# keyPressed method not working Java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, keypress, keyevent

Hi I am new to Java and I am trying to move a JPanel (Player) across a JFrame using the arrow keys but for some reason it is not working. I believe it is because the keyPressed method is not responding when a key is pressed but I don't really know.

This is the code for the Player class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Player extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    int x=0,y=0;
    public Player(){
        this.setBounds(x, y, 9, 9);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            this.setBounds(x, x-9, 9, 9);
        }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            this.setBounds(x, y+9, 9, 9);
        }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            this.setBounds(x+9, y, 9, 9);
        }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            this.setBounds(x-9, y, 9, 9);
        }

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
This is the code for the JFrame:
import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class Cave {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cave Generator");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

            Player p = new Player();
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems as you might need to `repaint` the Frame in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: So have you debugged into it? Is the method getting called, but with an unexpected key code? Are you calling setBounds but nothing is happening? You really need to do diagnostic work yourself.

Comment: I did debuging and the method is not being called

Comment: how do you add the `JPanel` to your frame? could you include that code aswell?

Comment: @OfriAdiv really? I tried your code, and keyPressed gets called, it just does not calculate the coordinates correctly. -> see my answer...

Comment: it doesn't work for me... i use eclipse if it matters

Comment: it doesn´t work for me either. If i put the adding of the keylistener and the `setFocusable` out of the class itself and into the `main` method it works for me (only after i did move the frame). [reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487369/jpanel-doesnt-response-to-keylistener-event)

Comment: Deleted my answer because another answer also fixes the second problem, which I forgot to mention in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with your code.

1. The first issue is that once you call the visible call on your frame than you are adding the player component on the frame.
2. You are not storing the last location of the player.

Make the below changes in your code and it should run:

**Cave**

```
public class Cave {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cave Generator");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Player p = new Player();
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Player**#*keyPressed*

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        y = y-9;
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        y = y+9;
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        x = x+9;
    }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        x = x-9;
    }
    this.setBounds(x, y, 9, 9);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot!