# Java KeyListener does not fire?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener

Normally I don't program in JAVA but for this project I need to. I got everything working except of the key listener. I want the program to react whenever a Key is pressed (doesn't matter wich one).

```
public class fullscreen extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {


public fullscreen() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
}
```

and then the KeyListener methods:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Key Pressed!");
}



@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

The MouseListener methods work without any problem. What did I do wrong with the KeyListener?

Comment: Do you have focus in your panel when pressing key?

Comment: Focus might be the problem: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487369/jpanel-doesnt-response-to-keylistener-event

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks a lot guys!!