# My JPanel is unable to listen for keyEvents?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, keyevent

I have built a snake game where a `JPanel` that implements a card layout manager is placed onto the `JFrame`. Three other `JPanels` are added to the card layout.

```
public void init () {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Don't let the snake hit the borders or you lose!", "Introduction to the Snake Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   appleCounter.label.setBorder (new LineBorder (Color.yellow, 1));
   mainPanel.setLayout (card);//CHANGING THE LAYOUT MANAGER FOR THE JPANEL TO CARDLAYOUT
   Screens [0] = new Screen ();//CREATING AN INSTANCE OF A JPANEL

   mainPanel.add (Screens [0], "one");//ADDING THE JPANEL TO THE CARD LAYOUT

   add (mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);//ADDING THE JPANEL TO THE JFRAME

   add (appleCounter.label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   pack ();

   setLocationRelativeTo (null);
   setVisible (true);
}
```

This is so that after the snake collides with the border of the frame, a `JDialog` appears asking if they'd like to try again. If the player clicks 'yes' the next `JPanel` from the card layout will appear.

```
if (xCoor < 0 || xCoor > 80 || yCoor < 0 || yCoor > 60) {//IF THE SNAKE COLLIDES WITH THE BORDER OF THE FRAME
   number = 1;
   collide = true;
   createApples ();
   stop ();//CALLING THE METHOD THAT I AM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH
}
```

However, I am having issues with the stop method because when the snake collides with the border & the player clicks "yes" the next JPanel from the card layout appears. But the JPanel doesn't listen for any key inputs from the player, as a result, the snake cannot change directions.

```
public void stop () {
 running = false;
 try {
 int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (this, "Do you want to play again?", "Opps looks like you lost", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
 if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
   if (digit < 3) {
     Frame.card.removeLayoutComponent (Frame.Screens [digit]);
     Frame.Screens [digit] = null;
     digit++;
     Frame.Screens [digit] = new Screen ();
     if (digit == 1) {
       Frame.card.removeLayoutComponent (Frame.Screens [digit]);
       Frame.Screens [digit] = null;

       Frame.mainPanel.add (Frame.Screens [digit], "two");
       Frame.card.removeLayoutComponent (Frame.Screens [digit]);
     } else if (digit == 2) {
       Frame.mainPanel.add (Frame.Screens [digit], "three");
     }
     } else if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
       System.exit (0);
     } else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
       System.exit (0);
     }
     thread.join ();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace ();
    }//CLOSE CATCH 
  }
```

The JPanel instances are created using the Screen class which extends from JPanel class, even though the two JPanels in the card layout `setFocusable` to true so it should throw `keyEvents`.

```
 public Screen () {
  setFocusable (true);//THE JPANEL COMPONENT WILL BE AN EVENT SOURCE, THROWING KEY EVENTS TO THE KEY INSTANCE
  addKeyListener (new Key ());//REGISTER THE KEY INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO KEY EVENTS
  setPreferredSize (new Dimension (WIDTH, HEIGHT));

  r = new Random ();

  apples = new ArrayList <Apple> ();

  start ();
 }
```

Here is the inner class which has the `keyPressed ()` that is called when the player clicks a directional key:

```
  public class Key implements KeyListener {
   public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
     int key = e.getKeyCode ();

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !left) {
        up = false;
        down = false;
        right = true;
     }

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !right) {
        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = true;
     }

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !down) {
        left = false;
        right = false;
        up = true;
     }

     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !up) {
        left = false;
        right = false;
        down = true;
     }
  }

   public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {}

   public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {}
```

I am a beginner at Java so I would appreciate it if when answering this question there is a minimal amount of technical language or that the answer is explained in a way a beginner can understand. To clarify only the first `Screen` instance created in the `init ()` listens for key inputs, the other two `Screen` instances cannot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPanel doesn't response to KeyListener event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487369/jpanel-doesnt-response-to-keylistener-event)

Comment: To receive key events your component needs to have focus, so you might also need to requestFocus. On an aesthetic appeal, please consider naming conventions. Eg. ClassName, instanceOfClassOrField. Also, putting a space after the name before the attached brackets, eg. `Screen [0]` or `e.getKeyCode ()` I find very frustrating.

Comment: @matt can u explain how i would get my other JPanels to requestFocus.

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).